# C# & ASP.NET MVC Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have scaffolded identity and it seemed like it works fine, but then I logged in, I click on the email, and it goes straight to the `Index` page, and doesn't show options like Change Password, Email, etc.

I can access these pages if I write their names in browser.

This is my `_Layout`

```
 @{
    if (ViewData.TryGetValue("ParentLayout", out var parentLayout) && parentLayout !=  null)
    {
        Layout = parentLayout.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "/Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}

<h1>Manage your account</h1>

<div>
    <h2>Change your account settings</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <partial name="_ManageNav" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
}
```

It seems like it does not load `_ManageNav` partial page. Does anyone know solution to it?

Comment: What does your startup/program class look like?

Comment: Found answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65015230/layout-for-identity-account-manage-pages-broken-after-scaffolding-full-net-iden
It needed to create _ViewStart.cshtml